# Why cant I use Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS in My Android App?

Tags: java, android

I have configured my android app to use java 8 as below

So why cant I use this Constant from `java.util.regex.Pattern`

e.g. `Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS`

```
private static final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("[\\p{Punct}']", Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS);
```

Here is my Gradle file.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion = "android-N"
    buildToolsVersion = "24.0.0 rc4"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.software.crucifix.my.app"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    jackOptions {
        enabled true
    }
}

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This constant is not part of the Android SDK ([Android - Pattern](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)). It seems it will be added in [API level N](http://msdx.github.io/androiddoc/docs/reference/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS) but has no influence on Android as stated in the description.

> This flag has **no effect on Android**, unicode character classes are always used.