# Parse football teams and result

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to parse an string to retrieve the home and away teams, and also the result of it.

So the strings can be something like this:

```
Football: Real Madrid 2-1 FC Barcelona
Football: Atletico de Madrid 4-2 Real Madrid
```

Let's say, you have the home team name, plus the result in {homeTeamGoals}-{awayTeamGoals} and then the away team name

I want to use regexp to parse the string and retrieve the team names and result. I thought of having something like this:

```
String PATTERN_SPORT = "([a-zA-Z]+ ?[0-9]?)"
String PATTERN_NAME = "(.*)"
String PATTERN_RESULT = "([0-9]*)-([0-9]*)"
String PATTERN_SPORT_AND_HOME_TEAM_RESULT_AWAY_TEAM = Pattern.compile("^" + PATTERN_SPORT + ": " + PATTERN_NAME + " " + PATTERN_RESULT + " ?"
    + PATTERN_NAME + "?$")
```

But it does not match, and I don't know why since I used for the pattern name (.*), any clue?

Comment: Note that you may get problems with e.g `Paris Saint-Germain` .

Comment: Did you run `.find()` or `.matches()` before trying to acces `.group()`s?

Comment: exactly, I also want that characters like - and + are included, but maybe I can restrict that, if a team name has -, then it should not have spaces around

Comment: hi Wiktor, I run matches, and it is false

Comment: Ah, I know the problem. Replace all spaces with `\s` and `compile` with `Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS` option.

Comment: You also assigned a `Pattern.compile` to a `String` :)

Comment: that's a mistake in the copy paste, actually I am using kotlin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure you match all Unicode whitespaces (the first one after `:` is a non-breaking space). Replacing all spaces with `\s` and `compile`ing with `Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS` option will solve the issue:

```
String PATTERN_SPORT = "([a-zA-Z]+\\s?[0-9]?)";
String PATTERN_NAME = "(.*)";
String PATTERN_RESULT = "([0-9]*)-([0-9]*)";
Pattern PATTERN_SPORT_AND_HOME_TEAM_RESULT_AWAY_TEAM = Pattern.compile("^" + PATTERN_SPORT + ":\\s" + PATTERN_NAME + "\\s" + PATTERN_RESULT + "\\s?"
    + PATTERN_NAME + "$", Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS);
```

[Java demo](https://ideone.com/bf5LX8):

```
String s = "Football: Real Madrid 2-1 FC Barcelona";
String PATTERN_SPORT = "([a-zA-Z]+\\s?[0-9]?)";
String PATTERN_NAME = "(.*)";
String PATTERN_RESULT = "([0-9]*)-([0-9]*)";
Pattern PATTERN_SPORT_AND_HOME_TEAM_RESULT_AWAY_TEAM = Pattern.compile("^" + PATTERN_SPORT + ":\\s" + PATTERN_NAME + "\\s" + PATTERN_RESULT + "\\s?" + PATTERN_NAME + "$", Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS);

Matcher matcher = PATTERN_SPORT_AND_HOME_TEAM_RESULT_AWAY_TEAM.matcher(s);
if (matcher.matches()){
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1)); 
    System.out.println(matcher.group(2)); 
    System.out.println(matcher.group(3)); 
    System.out.println(matcher.group(4)); 
    System.out.println(matcher.group(5)); 
}
```

Output:

```
Football
Real Madrid
2
1
FC Barcelona
```

Comment: Added the 5th capture to the demo.

Comment: I forgot to mention I am using android, so I can't use Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS, right?

Comment: @Manuelarte From what I remember, the shorthand char classes there are Unicode aware by default. You just to do not need it. Else, you may use `[\p{Z}\s]` instead of `\s`.

Answer (score 2):

I would use the following regex: `(\w*:)\s?(.*)\s?(\d{1,2}-\d{1,2})\s?(.*)` [see here](https://regex101.com/r/0WXpkL/3/)

- group 1 `(\w*:)` will match the sport and : (eventually you can improve this to take only the sport without the `:` -> just do `(\w*):`)
- group 2 `(.*)` first team name
- group 3 `(\d{1,2}-\d{1,2})` this will take any score (0-0 to 99-99)
- group 4 `(.*)` second team name

just ignore the `\s`. 
This will work only for your format (if you have other format the regex can be adjusted)

Java:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

class Test {
    public static void main(String [] args){
        String s = "Football: Hannover 96 3-3 1.FC Nuernberg";
        String PATTERN_SPORT = "(\\w*:)";
        String PATTERN_NAME = "(.*)";
        String PATTERN_RESULT = "(\\d{1,2}-\\d{1,2})";
        Pattern PATTERN_RESULTS= Pattern.compile("^" + PATTERN_SPORT + "\\s?" + PATTERN_NAME + "\\s?" + PATTERN_RESULT + "\\s?" + PATTERN_NAME + "$", Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS);

        Matcher matcher = PATTERN_RESULTS.matcher(s);
        if (matcher.matches()){
                System.out.println(matcher.group(1)); 
                System.out.println(matcher.group(2)); 
                System.out.println(matcher.group(3)); 
                System.out.println(matcher.group(4)); 
        }
    }
}
```

You can paste the [code](https://tio.run/#java-jdk) here and test it.

Output:

```
Football:
Hannover 96 
3-3
1.FC Nuernberg
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I use it in Android, so I can't use Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS, right?

Comment: yes -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37482787/why-cant-i-use-pattern-unicode-character-class-in-my-android-app

Comment: I get this:
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported flags: 256

Answer (score 0):

You can try this pattern: `(?<=: )(?P<home_team>[\w ]+) (?P<result>\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}) (?P<away_team>[\w ]+)`.

You might want to use different lookbehind: `(?<=Football: )` to parse only football results.

I also assumed, that one team won't score more than 100 goals :) `\d{1,2}` will match scores from range 0-99.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/NHZ9aL/1)